# Почему PhpStorm не видит функцию mysqli_connect()?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Выводит такую вот ошибку :

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\OSPanel\domains\ItalianFood\DB\db2.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\ItalianFood\index.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\ItalianFood\DB\db2.php on line 8

Если я пытаюсь открыть сайт через phpStorm то он выводит такую ошибку, а если открывать через Open Server в таком случае всё прекрасно работает, почему? Я изменил в php.ini extension'ы для mysqli как видел по рекомендациям, но всё равно не помогает.

Код:

```
   <?php

 $server = "localhost";
 $name = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $dbname = "Users";

      $conn2 = mysqli_connect($server, $name, $pass, $dbname);

   if(!$conn2 ){
     die("connection failed" .mysqli_connect_error());   
  }

       session_start();
 ?>
```

Comment: Что значит "*пытаюсь открыть сайт через phpStorm*" ?

Answer (score 0):

PHPSTORM редактор он не дает возможность mysqli чтоб подключится к mysql нужен сервер
(openserver, vagrant, laragon и т.д)